# Greenplum distribution key that depends on the distribution of other key

Tags: greenplum

There is a table A that is distributed by column x;

```
CREATE table A (x integer, y integer) distributed by (x);
```

And there is another table B which has the column "y" but not the "x".

```
CREATE TABLE B (y integer);
```

Is there any way we can distribute B according to the distribution of "y" on table A ? So we can join both tables using column "y" without needing to redistribute data between the segments? Basically meaning that the distribution of column "y" on table A drives the distribution of table B.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM A 
JOIN B using (y);
```

The problem being that table A is often joined to other tables distributed by "x" and that's why we don't want to change table A's distribution.

Column "y" is unique

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't but I wouldn't be that worried about it.  Do you filter table b or a when you join these two tables together?  If so, Greenplum will use that to only motion the data it needs to complete the data.

Secondly, if you are that worried about it, you could de-normalize table a by adding the columns from table b.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wanted to confirm there was no easy workaround or design strategy that could help (although we don't have much flexibility for the later one). Thank you.